# How to stop MapView from automatic scroll?

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios10, ios12, mapkitannotation

I have a `MKMapView` and some `MKAnnotation`. I want to select one of the `MKAnnotation` whenever user click on an item of my `UICollectionView`.
this is my code for selecting one of the `MKAnnotation`.

```
func showAnnotationForItemAt(index: Int){
    for item in map.annotations{
        if item.title == items[index]["title"].string{
            map.selectAnnotation(item, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

it works perfectly on iOS 12. but in iOS 10.3, map scrolls automatically to the annotation whenever I call `map.selectAnnotation(item, animated: true)`. How can I prevent map from auto scrolling after calling selectAnnotation. I want it to be like what it happens in iOS 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do animation `false`:

```
map.selectAnnotation(item, animated: false)
```